How to update feature flags in configuration file without restarting app?
I am using Microsoft Feature Management to implement feature flags in my application. I load the settings from a json file and use the flags in both the back end and front end. In the back end, I use the IFeatureManager to check if a feature is enabled, and for the front end, I pass the IOptions<CompanySettings> via a controller.
Program.cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
            => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {

                    SetupConfiguration(config, hostingContext.HostingEnvironment);
                    if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        config.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
                    }
                    config.Build();
                })
                ...
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                { services.AddFeatureManagement(context.Configuration.GetSection("Company:FeatureFlags"));
                });

static void SetupConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder builder, IHostEnvironment env)
           => builder.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                      .AddJsonFile("secrets/secrets.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddEnvironmentVariables();

Startup.cs
services.Configure<CompanyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Company"));

I am trying to figure out how I can update the feature flags in the secrets.json file and have the flags dynamically update in the back end and front end without restarting the app. I use the flags in Startup to register a handler based on a flag, in various classes and I also use the FeatureGate attribute on a controller to manage the features.
In the front end (typescript), it gets the CompanyOptions from a controller endpoint and saves it to a static variable that is used across the front end.
I tried using the IOptionsSnapshot and IOptionsMonitor but the features do not update in both the back end and front end.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

"I use the flags in Startup to register a handler based on a flag," by doing that, I really think you are depriving yourself of the option to activate during runtime. Maybe you might need to register the handler but respect the flag inside that handler instead?

Have you tried setting up a separate project to single out that issue alone and get it to work there, first?

I moved the code to check the flag into the handler, using IOptionsMonitor. The value does not update when I update the secrets.json during runtime.

Are you updating the correct secrets.json? I.e. actually the one that your application is monitoring? (Been there, done that ;) )

Yes, I am sure :) When I restart the app, the changes take effect.

How do you start it? By hitting "run" in the IDE? Do you build it? - Because that might actually include copying the modified file to its runtime-path. Just for good measure: Perform a system-wide search for that json ... if only one is found, we can agree to be sure.

Ah so it does copy it to the debug folder. You're saying I would need to modify that file during runtime in order for the changes to take effect? Would the same apply in production?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"You're saying I would need to modify that file during runtime" - Exactly.

That did not work though.
